# Lock error while running program in Qt/C++

Tags: qt

I get the following error messages,while running programme in Qt/c++
Semop unlock failure Invalid argument
Semop lock failure Invalid argument

Does somebody know,why this messages come?

Comment: which program ? Which Os ? With version of Qt ? Any sources avialable ? Did you develop it yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on linux, see this forum thread:

http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2008-03/msg01042.html